# Is it possible to cast struct to another?

Tags: c, sockets, casting, struct

Any one could describe how `(struct sockaddr *)&server` works here? Is it possible to cast bigger struct to smaller struct?

See these structs:

```
// IPv4 AF_INET sockets:
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;          // load with inet_pton()
};

struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

This is the main program:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
 {
        int socket_desc;
        struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995940/casting-one-c-structure-into-another || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766229/casting-one-struct-pointer-to-other-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is refered as [Type Punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning). Here, both structures have the same size, so there is no question of struct size. Although you can cast almost anything to anything, doing it with structures is error-prone.

Comment: How connect() functions can access to inet_address that is stored in `struct in_addr`?

Comment: Something like `((struct sockaddr_in *) server->sin_addr.s_addr)`

Comment: printf ("addr: %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in *) server->sin_addr.s_addr)); will produce this error: socket.c:50:54: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct sockaddr_in’)     why?

Comment: My problem is solved. thanks. ((struct sockaddr_in *) server)->sin_addr.s_addr

Answer (score 6):

This is C's form of "inheritance" (notice the quotes). This works because C does not care about the underlying data in an address, just what you represent it as.

The function determines what structure it actually is by using the sa_family field, and casting it into the proper `sockaddr_in` inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast sockaddr_in to sockaddr, but you cannot usually cast ANY struct to ANY other and assume that things will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

In C, it's possible to cast anything to anything.  You could even omit the cast to (struct sockaddr*), and probably just get a compiler warning.