# casting between sockaddr pointer and sockaddr_in pointer

Tags: c++, network-programming

I came across a socket programming tutorial in which it is quoted

> *"a pointer to a struct sockaddr_in can be cast to a pointer to a struct sockaddr **and vice-versa**"*

I dont understand how can sockaddr_in be cast to sockaddr. Casting a pointer of *Big* type to *Small* type should give UD behavior.

```
struct sockaddr {
unsigned short sa_family; // address family, AF_xxx
char sa_data[14]; // 14 bytes of protocol address
};


struct sockaddr_in {
short int sin_family; // Address family, AF_INET
unsigned short int sin_port; // Port number
struct in_addr sin_addr; // Internet address
unsigned char sin_zero[8]; // Same size as struct sockaddr
};
```

How can the cast not be undefined? Isn't it unsafe to cast these to each other?

If i have a class A having only two ints and class B having 4 ints. And if i have a pointer of type B and i cast it to type A then sure i can fetch the first two elements. But if class A has 2 chars declared first and 2 ints declared later then the pointers would not right fetch the values since the object layout in this case would be different.

**Edit 1:**

```
class Anu
{
public:
    char a;
    int b;
    Anu()
    {
        a='a';
    }
};
class Anurag
{
public:
    Anurag() { a=4;}
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
int main()
{
        Anu objanu;
        Anurag objanurag;
        Anurag *ptrAnurag= &objanurag;
        ptrAnurag= (Anurag*)&objanu;
        cout<<ptrAnurag->a; //Some weird value here
        return 0;
}
```

Assuming i change the example so that both classes have same size by adjusting the variables types...still the object layout might be different even though the size remains the same.

Comment: How are they different size? sockaddr: 2+14=16, sockaddr_in:2+2+4+8=16

Comment: Yes you are right. But the object layout of sockaddr and sockaddr_in would be different even though the size appears to be similar. The first thing that would be stored in sockaddr would be 2 bytes representing sa_family. However in sockaddr_in object the first thing stored would be an int of 4 bytes representing sin_family. The result would be UD if sockaddr_in type pointer points to sockaddr or viceversa.

Comment: no no but sin_family is not 'int' it is 'short int' thank the c++ guys for that but I use just 'short' to short that issues :)

Comment: what about sin_port vs sa_data types?

Answer (score 6):

I'll add to @gsamaras answer by saying that Undefined Behaviour doesn't always means that bad things are about to happen. Undefined Behaviour actually says "we* don't provide any specifications on what should happen next if XYZ occurs".

(*the C++ standard).

this is the place where the OS takes place and say "it is defined by us".

although casting unrelated structs (`sockaddr_in`,`sockaddr`) may be undefined behaviour by the standard, the OS API specify that it is valid with their API.

Comment: Thank you for providing a more general aspect, here is my upvote.

Comment: @David : could you please look at my Edit1 part of the question

Answer (score 1):

The different sizes don't matter.  Just like you can pass strings of different lengths to the various string-handling functions, you can pass `struct sockaddr` of different lengths to the various socket-handling functions.

The size of the `struct sockaddr` is interpreted by the called function per the contents of the `sa_family` member of the structure.  Note also that all functions that take a `struct sockaddr *` address also take a `socklen_t` argument that holds the size of the structure being passed.

For example, the [`struct sockaddr_un`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) structure is 110 bytes:

```
   struct sockaddr_un {
       sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
       char        sun_path[108];            /* pathname */
   };
```

The called function such as  [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) or [`getpeername()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) have declarations similar to

```
int getpeerame(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

for the very reason that the size(s) of various socket structures vary.

Note that the first member of every `struct sockaddr_???` is the `sa_family`.  Thus it's always in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

They are of **equal size**, so no, you don't get any *UB*!

Proof:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sockaddr {
  unsigned short sa_family; // address family, AF_xxx
  char sa_data[14]; // 14 bytes of protocol address
};

// src: http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html
struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
};

struct sockaddr_in {
  short int sin_family; // Address family, AF_INET
  unsigned short int sin_port; // Port number
  struct in_addr sin_addr; // Internet address
  unsigned char sin_zero[8]; // Same size as struct sockaddr
};

int main (void) {
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned short) + sizeof(char) * 14);
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(short int) + sizeof(unsigned short int) + sizeof(struct in_addr) + sizeof(unsigned char) * 8);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
16
16
```

A good comment: sockaddr: 2+14=16, sockaddr_in:2+2+4+8=16 – Amer Agovic

You may also want to take a look at this question: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

---

Please, check this question: [Is it possible to cast struct to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998639/is-it-possible-to-cast-struct-to-another)

I am copying the answer of Benoit here too:

> This is refered as [Type Punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning). Here, both structures have the same size, so there is no question of struct size. Although you can cast almost anything to anything, doing it with structures is error-prone.

and this one by Richard J. Ross III too:

> This is C's form of "inheritance" (notice the quotes). This works because C does not care about the underlying data in an address, just what you represent it as.
>
> The function determines what structure it actually is by using the sa_family field, and casting it into the proper sockaddr_in inside the function.

Comment: Yes you are right. But the object layout of sockaddr and sockaddr_in would be different even though the size appears to be similar. The first thing that would be stored in sockaddr would be 2 bytes representing sa_family. However in sockaddr_in object the first thing stored would be an int of 4 bytes representing sin_family. The result would be UD if sockaddr_in type pointer points to sockaddr or viceversa.

Comment: The size of the base structure that has it's address cast to `struct sockaddr *` doesn't matter - see `struct sockaddr_un`, which is 110 bytes.  Every function that takes a `struct sockaddr *` also takes a `socklen_t` for this reason.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

Comment: @gsamaras: Thnx for the answer. Could you please look at my Edit1 part of the question. Things are still little unclear to me.

Comment: You are welcome @anurag86. I think in your example, the classes are not of equal size!

Comment: @gsamaras: if i do getaddinfo this way : `getaddrinfo(myhost, myport, &hints, &res);`  , i get the result in _res_  and then i can use the c style cast this way :
`struct sockaddr_in *mytest = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;` .   It works fine. But if i use c++ style `static_cast` then it doesnt work :
    `struct sockaddr_in *mytest = static_cast<struct sockaddr_in *>(res->ai_addr);` .  I am not sure what type of cast is being used internally by C. But it is evident from the example that it is not `static_cast` . Shouldn't the `static_cast` work?

Comment: I would let it in the C way @anurag86, since structs are C elements.

Comment: The fact that they have "the same size" (or not) has absolutely no relevance whatsoever in this case. C does not help here either: the behavior is undefined in C as much as it is undefined in C++.