# Correctly Allocate And Fill Frame In FFmpeg

Tags: c, opencv, memory-leaks, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am filling a `Frame` with a BGR image for encoding, and I am getting a memory leak. I think I got to the source of the problem but it appears to be a library issue instead. Since FFmpeg is such a mature library, I think I am misusing it and I would like to be instructed on how to do it correctly.

I am allocating a `Frame` using:

```
AVFrame *bgrFrame = av_frame_alloc();
```

And later I allocate the image in the `Frame` using:

```
av_image_alloc(bgrFrame->data, bgrFrame->linesize, bgrFrame->width, bgrFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, 32);
```

Then I fill the image allocated using:

```
av_image_fill_pointers(bgrFrame->data, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, bgrFrame->height, originalBGRImage.data, bgrFrame->linesize);
```

Where `originalBGRImage` is an OpenCV `Mat`.

And this has a memory leak, apparently, `av_image_alloc()` allocates memory, and `av_image_fill_pointers()` also allocates memory, on the same pointers (I can see `bgrFrame->data[0]` changing between calls).

If I call

```
av_freep(&bgrFrame->data[0]);
```

After `av_image_alloc()`, it's fine, but if I call it after `av_image_fill_pointers()`, the program crashes, even though `bgrFrame->data[0]` is not `NULL`, which I find very curious.

Looking FFmpeg's `av_image_alloc()` [source code](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.6/imgutils_8c_source.html#l00192), I see it calls `av_image_fill_pointers()` twice inside it, once allocating a buffer `buff`....and later in `av_image_fill_pointers()` [source code](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.6/imgutils_8c_source.html#l00110), `data[0]` is substituted by the image pointer, which is (I think) the source of the memory leak, since `data[0]` was holding `buf` from the previous `av_image_alloc()` call.

So this brings the final question: **What's the correct way of filling a frame with an image?**.

Comment: Since the data is already there, you could use `avpicture_fill`, which does not allocate. In any case, you should only allocate one frame and reuse that. Also, have a look if you really need `av_freep` or `av_free`.

Comment: But as far as I know, I need to give a frame for encoding, how I convert the AVPicture into a AVFrame?

Answer (score 4):

You should allocate your frame once.

```
AVFrame* alloc_picture(enum PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
{
AVFrame *f = avcodec_alloc_frame();
if (!f)
    return NULL;
int size = avpicture_get_size(pix_fmt, width, height);
uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(size);
if (!buffer) {
    av_free(f);
    return NULL;
}
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)f, buffer, pix_fmt, width, height);
return f;
}
```

Yes, the cast (AVPicture*) is allowed https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498359/2079934 .
In subsequent frames, you can write into the this frame. Since your OpenCV raw data is BGR and you need RGB or YUV, you can use `sws_scale`. In my application, I mirror vertically:

```
struct SwsContext* convertCtx = sws_getContext(width, height, PIX_FMT_RGB24, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
avpicture_fill(&pic_raw, (uint8_t*)pixelBuffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height);
// flip
pic_raw.data[0] += (height - 1) * pic_raw.linesize[0]; 
pic_raw.linesize[0] *= -1;
sws_scale(convertCtx, pic_raw.data, pic_raw.linesize, 0, height, f->data, f->linesize);
out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outputBuffer, outputBufferSize, f);
```

(You can adapt PIX_FMT_RGB24 to your needs and read from `cv::Mat` without copying data.)

Comment: I got it to work using `av_fill_arrays()` and I pass my BGR image pointer and allocated frame (which is only being allocated once). I am also using `sws_scale()` for conversion, the only piece missing was the `av_fill_arrays()` actually.

Answer (score 0):

`av_fill_arrays()` does the job. It will fill the frame's `data[]` and `linesizes[]` but not reallocating any memory.

Comment: I was looking "for av_fill_arrays" but couldn't find it. I couldn't find the source code or the docu. Is it depreciated?

Comment: I don't know, last time I used it was in 2016, but I can find `av_image_fill_arrays` on Google, maybe it's the same?

Answer (score 0):

Too late for answer. But after take many hours, i want to share.
In document

```
 /**
    * AVBuffer references backing the data for this frame. All the pointers in
    * data and extended_data must point inside one of the buffers in buf or
    * extended_buf. This array must be filled contiguously -- if buf[i] is
    * non-NULL then buf[j] must also be non-NULL for all j < i.
    *
    * There may be at most one AVBuffer per data plane, so for video this array
    * always contains all the references. For planar audio with more than
    * AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS channels, there may be more buffers than can fit in
    * this array. Then the extra AVBufferRef pointers are stored in the
    * extended_buf array.
    */
AVBufferRef *buf[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
```

Then `buf` is "smart pointer" for `data` (`extended_buf` for `extended_data`)
for example, i using image one linesize only

```cpp
int size = av_image_get_buffer_size(AVPixelFormat::AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA, width, height, 1);
AVBufferRef* dataref = av_buffer_alloc(size);//that for av_frame_unref

memcpy(dataref->data, your_buffer, size );

AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, dataref->data, AVPixelFormat::AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA, source->width, source->height, 1
frame->buf[0] = dataref;
```

[av_frame_unref](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/frame_8c_source.html#l00486) will unref `frame->buf` and free pointer if ref count to zero